# Ad-rotator Asp.Net Control on my 2010 master page does not work on child pages

Tags: 2010, master-page, asp.net

I have a SharePoint 2010 site I'm setting up where I want to have an **AdRotator** on every page, so I added the control to my **master page** in SharePoint Designer.

However when I look at my site, all the **configuration settings** on my **AdRotator** are missing and it looks as though it can't find the **Adverts.xml** file (in one of my site assets document libraries) in order to display anything and I just get a **missing image graphic** instead.

Comment: We need more information to help answer your question. Can you please edit it and add further specific details such the AdRotator snippet from your master page? Screenshots may help as well.

Comment: Are the properties for the control (such as the path to your Adverts.xml) passed in properly when you added it to the masterpage? You'll need a `<Properties>` tag, with one or more `<Property Name='someProperty' Value='someValue'/>` tags inside.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the problem was in relative path which in the case of master pages is calculated in relation to the mater page gallery (/_catalogs/masterpage) instead of the site or site collection root (/).

In many cases the URL such as "SiteAssets" will turn to "/_catalogs/masterpage/SiteAssets" when rendered, that will cause the unexpected behavior as described..